# Executing if @@rowcount>0 resets @@rowcount to 0. Why?

Tags: t-sql

[Link](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2010/08/09/proper-usage-of-rowcount.aspx)

> @@Rowcount is used to inform the number of rows affected for the last
>   select,insert,update or delete statements
>
> ```
> declare @row int select 100 if @@rowcount>0  set @row=@@rowcount ...
> ```
>
> The above will return 0 because as soon as `if @@rowcount>0` is executed
>   it is reset to 0 as it doesn't return any rows. So always assign to
>   variable first

Why does statement `if @@rowcount>0` reset `@@rowcount` to 0? Isn't the value of  `@@rowcount` affected only by select,insert,update and delete statements?

thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is affected by the last statement. Like this SET statement

```
Declare @row int
select 100 union all select 200 union all select 300
set @row = @@rowcount;
SELECT @row, @@rowcount
```

If you read the [actual Microsoft SQL Server Docs on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx), it gives examples of what statements affect `@@ROWCOUNT`. For example "such as" implies other statements like IF will also set it to zero

> Statements such as USE, SET `<option>,` DEALLOCATE CURSOR, CLOSE CURSOR, BEGIN TRANSACTION or COMMIT TRANSACTION reset the ROWCOUNT value to 0.

Comment: 1 - As far as I understand it, reason why @@rowcount returned 1 and not 0 is because of "SELECT @row, @@rowcount" query affecting one row. But I thought the term "number of rows affected" was used when sql statement dealt with actual rows in DB tables, but your select statement doesn't access any rows, so why does @@rowcount return 1?

Comment: 2 - Hope this question makes some sense - if we were to nitpick, doesn't @@rowcount return the number of rows ALREADY affected by select statement? If so, then "SELECT @row, @@rowcount" should return 0 for @@rowcount, since select statement isn't yet fully completed at the time it retrieves a value from @@rowcount, and as such no rows have been affected yet?!

Comment: @user702769: The @@rowcount in `SELECT @row, @@rowcount` is affected by the `set @row = @@rowcount;` above it. A SELECT can not read it's own @@rowcount

Comment: I'm really sorry for dragging this, but doesn't set @row = @@rowcount; reset @@rowcount to 0?

Comment: @user702769: According to MSDN, @@rowcount should be zero after a SET. However, don't confuse the "xx rows affected message" with @@rowcount. IIRC (can't test here) SET will give "1 row(s) affected" but @@ROWCOUNT will be zero.

Comment: Uhm, when running your code, "SELECT @row, @@rowcount" returns 1 for @@rowcount ( which means @@rowcount is 1 ), while you say it should return 0 for @@rowcount?

Comment: @user702769: MSDN states that. Personally, I thought it would have been 1 but I couldn't test before posting. So is MSDN wrong?

Comment: The MSDN link is talking about `SET <option>`. Presumably `SET @variable` will come under the category "Statements that make a simple assignment always set the @@ROWCOUNT value to 1."

Comment: @Martin Smith: correct. the option bit has been lost above. I didn't look at the article again. Will fix above

Comment: ok, so "set @row = @@rowcount;" seting @@rowcount to 1 is a correct behavior. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I faced similar issue using sybase, which indicates that something might be wrong with "if".

```
declare @counter1 int
declare @counter2 int

select @counter1 = @@rowcount
if @@rowcount = 0 return
select @counter2 = @@rowcount
```

the output is:
counter1 = 3
counter2 = 0

I would expect 3(original one) or 1(because of Select).

This is even more strange because of 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278452893271.html

"The @@rowcount is **not** reset to zero by any statement which does not affect rows, **such as an IF** statement."
on other hand there is a lot of confusion how it really works(based on discussion in internet)

At the end in my solution in first line I assign @@rowcount to variable and my logic is based on that variable

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised to discover (the hard way) that in SQL Server @@rowcount is reset by an "if" statement.