# Why is @@rowcount equal to 1 when run in complete isolation?

Tags: t-sql, rowcount

According to the Microsoft [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) documentation,

> Statements that make a simple assignment always set the @@ROWCOUNT
> value to 1. No rows are sent to the client. Examples of these
> statements are: SET @local_variable, RETURN, READTEXT, and select
> without query statements such as SELECT GETDATE() or SELECT 'Generic
> Text'.

Somebody else on Stackoverflow also asked [why @@rowcount equals 1 when no rows are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102805/rowcount-returning-1-when-no-update-made).  However, that question used an update statement.

My confusion starts with this example, where no other statements appear:

[image]

Reading further into this (*[Executing if @@rowcount>0 resets @@rowcount to 0. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705509/executing-if-rowcount0-resets-rowcount-to-0-why)*), I then did a second test:

[image]

**I'm curious to understand please why @@rowcount equals 1 when no other statements are used?**  Is it because the actual `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` statement itself causes an update of @@rowcount?

Comment: If I run `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` in it's own window, I get 0, not 1. I can't replicate it [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0448e81b9af01e7e350d20b9bfd291c).

Comment: Well now I'm even more confused... I've tried swapping connections, running it against tempdb.  It always returns 1.

Comment: I strongly suspect the difference stems from SSMS doing *something* before opening a new tab. Trying to check with profiler. @Larnu are you using ssms?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I tend to be using ADS (as SSMS isn't available on Linux). Gave SSMS a go in my WIndows 11 VM and that did replicate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running SSMS on windows, I indeed get OP's behaviour. By both doing an inputbuffer check and by using the profiler, it seems that when you open a new query window, ssms performs the following batch:

```
select @@spid;
select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel');
```

This results in that default ace.

Comment: Great work, thank you.  Would you say that that's a SSMS bug?  It seems very strange to me when other people above have seen different results on different platforms?

Comment: Hmmm..."bug" seems like a stretch. I can hardly think of a case where I would be using @@rowcount as my first line. Still, as indicated by Larnu, it is probably an SSMS thing.

Comment: Yes, running `@@ROWCOUNT` as the first statement is like counting your chicks before they've hatched; it's a meaningless number.